# コードを書くと「エントリポイントにmainメソッドを含んでいない」とでます。

Tags: c#

以下のコードを開始すると

```
重大度レベル  コード 説明  プロジェクト  ファイル    行   抑制状態
エラー CS5001  プログラムは、エントリ ポイントに適切な静的 'Main' メソッドを含んでいません。 Project26   C:\Users\aozaki hinagi\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Project26\Project26\CSC    1   アクティブ
```

と表示されます。

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;

namespace Chap5
{
    class DnsGetHostAddresses
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //ホスト名を取得
            string hostName = Dns.GetHostName();

            //IPアドレス一覧を取得
            IPAddress[] addresses = Dns.GetHostAddresses(hostName);
            foreach (IPAddress address in addresses)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("アドレス表記:" + address.ToString());

                //IPアドレスのバイト配列を,を挟んで出力
                Console.WriteLine(
                    "バイト列:{0}\n", string.Join(",", address.GetAddressBytes()));
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

しかし、mainを書いているのに含んでいないとエラーが出るのがよくわかりません。
どなたか教えていただけますでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: マルチポスト https://teratail.com/questions/109854

Answer (score 1):

経験上、上記の質問がある時は何かの弾みでビルドアクションが変わっている場合が多いです。
下記についてご確認ください。

1. マルチポスト先の回答にあるようにメインプロジェクトの`スタートアップオブジェクト`が誤っている
   → 「(設定なし)」など適切な設定に戻す
2. ソリューションの`スタートアッププロジェクト`が想定外のプロジェクトになっている
   → DnsGetHostAddressesクラスを含むプロジェクトを右クリックして「スタートアップ プロジェクトに設定」する
3. DnsGetHostAddressesクラスの.csファイルについて、`ビルドアクション`が「コンパイル」になっていない
   → ソリューションエクスプローラーで上記csファイルを選択し、プロパティのビルドアクションが「コンテンツ」や「埋め込みリソース」などになっていたら「コンパイル」に戻す

Comment: ありがとうございます。最初にスタートアップオブジェクトの位置がわからず、とりあえず一度vsを閉じてまた開いてみたら、ソースコードを開始できました。せっかくの回答を活かせず申し訳ありません。あなたをベストアンサーに選びたいのですが、どこにその為のボタンがあるかがわかりません。とにかく、ありがとうございました。

Comment: ベストアンサーのボタンは、回答左側の緑色をしたチェックマークです :)